# Three.js IE support

Tags: windows-runtime, three.js, webgl

I'm developing a windows 8 (WinJS) game using Three.js. It contains several materials (about 50) generated by Blender and its export on Three.js tool. I'm facing an issue when launching the game on "old" devices (2009). I have some FPS problems:

- Development machine (good hardware):

  - **IE inside Windows 8 app**: 60 FPS (very good)
  - **Firefox**: 60 FPS (very good)
- "Old" machine:

  - **IE inside Windows 8 app**: 7-8 FPS (so bad)
  - **Firefox**: 60 FPS (very good)

Any idea?

Comment: make sure that the version of IE are the same on both the machines and the old machine has all the updates of IE installed.

Comment: It's the same browser in the Windows 8 app than the desktop one because it is a WinJS project so it's the same browser